# .net Timer runs at different speed on multiple computers

Tags: .net, performance, timer

I have a C# application working on multiple computers connected to a server.

Upon signaled by the server, the clients start a countdown clock, which is using `System.Timers.Timer`. All computers start at the same time (I have managed to keep the offset very low, well under half a second). However, as you watch two computers side by side, one of them is clearly going faster than the other. I have added a check every minute to re-sync them, but the process is very noticeable and the result if undesirable.

I compared all 3 Timers in `.net` and this was the best one, but it's still way off. I'm talking about a whole second difference in 2 minutes if I don't adjust.

Is there any other timer that I can use that will actually tick every second if I set it to that in all computers?

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve?  Why do each of the timers have to fire at exactly the same interval across 3 servers?

Comment: 1 server, multiple clients. The clients are showing a countdown timer, which updates the screen on every second.

Comment: ok so why does it matter if the clients are in sync or not?  Is it an issue if their screens update at slightly different speeds?

Comment: The timer runs different for each client. While one of them sees 10:34 left in the clock, for example, the other is seeing 10:29 left, so one of them is wrong.